# How do I use my second move in Pokemon GO?

Tags: pokemon-go

I was looking at my Pokemon's stats when I noticed that my Pokemon actually has two moves available.

[image]

However, I could only use the top move in a recent Gym battle. Why is this?

Also, what do the blue bars represent?

Comment: Does the game not explain any of this stuff? I'm just seeing a lot of questions and self answers from you today and it makes me scared to play because I feel like it's going to be tricky!

Comment: @Ash Some of these things are, some aren't as well explained as they should be. I'm just getting free rep and building up the answers here. ^^

Comment: you will want to be careful, if people think you are just seeding stuff for rep, it's likely to be ill recieved.

Comment: I personally appreciate it. IMO the UX is pretty poor, in that there are a lot of features that are ill explained and unintuitive. The blue bars under the second move is one such thing, to me. I see this screen and can kind of figure out a few things, like the top move is probably the basic attack and has a power of 10, and the second move is a special attack and has a power of 50. But what are those blue bars? Do they represent max power? Crit? Special attack? PP? I have no clue

Comment: @Ash: I can confirm that the game has rubbish in game help and tutorials are no good. If I didn't have friends playing I'd have had to google how to throw a pokeball. You'd think they'd have at least explained how to catch pokemon well, right? :(

Comment: Took me a couple of attempts to figure out how to use the first move, so.. Yeah

Comment: @awestover89 Have to agree. I believe that if it weren't for the fact that the app is an official Nintendo Pokemon game, it would have been dropped from the popular list a long time ago. It's not very user friendly. That being said, the more (good) questions about the app we can get on SE, the better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you use your charged attack has now changed as of [12/8/2017](https://pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/en/post/ver-update-120817). Previously, you were required to press and hold on your Pokémon to use your charged attack. In this update, Niantic added a new button dedicate to performing charged attacks

> Updated the battle interface to include a dedicated button for performing a Charged Attack.

Using an image from [Google images](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/WnAbXEqQB_8/maxresdefault.jpg), you can see this new button, along with the charged bars which were once on the top left, on the bottom of your screen.

[image: New charged attack button]

Answer (score 20):

> **Note:** This answer has been obsoleted since [version 0.85.2](https://pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/en/post/ver-update-120817) (released 2017-12-08).
>
> Please see [wondercricket's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/322939/76693) for the new way of using a charge move.

To use a Pokemon's second move, you must press and hold on the Pokemon during a battle. The screen will "shrink" and gain a letterbox effect, and the Pokemon will use its second attack.

However, the second attack can only be used when it's "charged" by using regular attacks repeatedly. During a Gym battle, you can see how charged the attack is by looking at the blue bars.

As you can see by the screenshot in the question, there are two bars. This represents that you can use the second attack twice, provided both bars are charged.

After depleting the bars by using the second attack, you may re-charge them to re-enable the second attack.

Comment: This answer is now outdated as of the 12/08/17 update to the game. see [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/322939/47011)

Answer (score 1):

The bars represent "Charges" of your special move, you can store up charges of special up to the number of bars, with smaller bars filling quicker. Essentially you could have 1 bar dealing 100 damage, or 4 bars dealing 25 damage and they would take the same time to fill up, but you would cast the 100 once and the 25 4 times.

Hold attack to use it when charged.

Comment: In the case of the OP's screenshot, if you filled 2 bars, and then used Body Slam, would it do 2x 50 dmg? Or would 2 bars do 50dmg, and 1 bar half of that?

Comment: in other words, is it 50 dmg per bar, or 50 dmg if both bars are filled?

Answer (score -1):

You're inventing new rules. Two bars means you need two bars to perform the attack. Damage will be 50 per attack as always.