# What is the difference between the dashed and solid attack bars?

Tags: pokemon-go

I was flipping through my Pokemon list to see which kind of attacks they had, and I notice there was a small different between the attacks. Some attacks contained a dashed blue bar where as others contained a solid blue bar.

What is the difference and significance between the two?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related to [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272658/how-do-i-use-my-second-move-in-pokemon-go).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The bars represent how much your secondary attack must be charged before being able to be used. A long bar must be charged to full before being used, and can only be used once before having to be charged again. The smaller bars only need one of the bars to be filled before being able to be used, and several charges of the attack can be stored, as only one bar is used per secondary attack.

They also are representative of the general strength of the attack. Attacks with many smaller bars deal significantly less damage per attack, but can be used more frequently, and larger bars hit much harder per attack, but take much longer to be charged.

Also, the damage amount listed to the right of the move is calculated per bar, and not split between them. The bars simply represent the amount of uses that can be stored, and how much charge is needed per use. The damage is therefore per use.

Comment: Ah ha. I figured it had to deal with the power of the attack. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: @Wondercricket no problem. Happy to help.

Comment: For anyone wondering: Double-Tap = Primary Attack, Long-Tap = Secondary Attack.

Comment: OK so if we have determined segmented bars means multiple uses that's great, vs single use long bar. But the most important part was left out. A 50 dmg single bar, vs a 50 dmg double bar. Does the double bar do 25 dmg per bar, or 2 attacks of 50 dmg? That will make a huge difference in our understanding of the bars, since a short bar of 50 dmg is much better than a single long bar of 50 dmg.

Comment: Does the number to the right of the bars represent the damage that will be dealt during each blue dash turn (i.e. 3 x 40 = 120 total) or does it represent the sum of the damage dealt when adding all the damage dealt across all blue dash turns (i.e. 40 total)?

Answer (score 4):

They all represent the number of times the attack can be used when fighting. The solid one means it's usable one time before needing a recharge.