# How do I interpret the "Move" information for each Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

Each Pokemon you capture has two moves, listed on the profile displayed when you select them.  According to [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272658/how-do-i-use-my-second-move-in-pokemon-go) question, one is a 'standard' and one is a 'special' attack, which requires charging before use.

However, I'm not clear on how to interpret the information the page tells me.  For example, here is a Golbat and an Oddish:

[image: Golbat][image: Oddish]

Presumably the ones with the blue lines are the specials, but what does the size and quantity of the blue lines indicate?  What about the number at the right hand side?